# Creating a object of list using Factorybot for test in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Before it works like:

Factory definition:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :foo_result_item, class: "Foo::Result::Item" do
    name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    url { Faker::Internet.url }
  end
end
```

Called from spec:

```
FactoryBot.build_list(:foo_result_item, 10)
```

But now I want it to be called as an object but not as lists

```
FactoryBot.build(:foo_result)
```

How could I define the factory? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do and why. Could you maybe describe the test scenario you're trying to do? That'll help people look at how FactoryBot can help you do it.

Comment: If you just want to create a single FooResult from the factory then you would use `create` or `build` and not `build_list`.

Comment: @max Sorry that I made a mistake. What I wanted should be `build` but not `build_list` and I have edited the question.

Comment: The question still doesn't make sense. You don't have to change anything in the factory. Maybe just start by reading the README?

Comment: I understand the question, but don't know the answer.  They want `build(:foo_result)` to return a list of 10 `foo_result_items`.